# Interactive Graphs in R using rggobi

Tags: r, graph, interactive, rggobi

From the following xml code:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<Company >
 <shareprice>
  <timeStamp> 12:00:00.01</timeStamp>
  <Price>  25.02</Price>
 </shareprice>

 <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:00.02</timeStamp>
  <Price>  15</Price>
 </shareprice>



    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:01.025</timeStamp>
        <Price>  15.02</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:01.031</timeStamp>
        <Price>  18.25</Price>
    </shareprice>



    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:01.039</timeStamp>
        <Price>  18.54</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:01.050</timeStamp>
        <Price> 16.52</Price>
    </shareprice>


    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:02.01</timeStamp>
        <Price>  17.50</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:03.01</timeStamp>
        <Price>  25.02</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:05.02</timeStamp>
        <Price>  30</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:11.025</timeStamp>
        <Price>  32.25</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:12.031</timeStamp>
        <Price>  26.05</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:15.039</timeStamp>
        <Price>  18.54</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:19.050</timeStamp>
        <Price> 16.52</Price>
    </shareprice>


    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:01:02.01</timeStamp>
        <Price>  17.50</Price>
    </shareprice>
</Company>
```

and using the following R code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library (XML)
test.df <- xmlToDataFrame(file.choose())
test.df
sapply(test.df, class) 
test.df$timeStamp <- strptime(as.character(test.df$timeStamp), "%H:%M:%OS")
test.df$Price <- as.numeric(as.character(test.df$Price))
sapply(test.df, class)
options("digits.secs"=3)
summary (test.df)
with(test.df, plot(timeStamp, Price))
sd (test.df$Price)
mean(test.df$timeStamp)
test.df$timeStamp <- test.df[1,"timeStamp"] + cumsum(runif(7)*60)
summary(test.df)
qplot(timeStamp,Price,data=test.df,geom=c("point","line"))
Price <- summary(test.df$Price)
print (Price)
```

I would like to create an interactive graph that would allow a user to click on a point and get information on the the value of the point (eg if the value jumped a reason so), I would like to be able to put this interactive graph on a web page. It has been suggested to use GGOBI to do this, while others say it is possible to remain in R and use the rggobi library. As I have no experience of this I thought I'd ask for some pointers either directly or to a specific resource (one can spend years searching the net and not find anything)

Under the graph I would like to print out the summary of the  Price. At the moment I run the code in a BATCH file on windows and it returns the graphs in a pdf file but not the summary print. Is there a way to set up the code / BATCH file so that it can produce the interactive graph and summary?

Comment: Ggobi has nothing to do with the web. You are looking at the wrong technology.

Comment: It would be nice, for future posts, if instead of posting the xml, instead you loaded it into R, applied all transformations you wanted, then paste the output of `dput(dest.df)` into your question. That would save answerers a few steps.

Comment: I will try that next time. Am I correct in assuming I can run dput(test.df) at the end of the R code I have and paste the structure(list(.... into the question?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for some pointers:

there´s [Rapache](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rapache/)

and you could possibly do the drawing with [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/)

plus i found this [link](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/archives/2007/10/how_to_make_a_c.html) on the topic

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Anthony, I assume that you were referring to *Identify* function available in GGobi. You can use *Tools > Save Display Description* and the `DescribeDisplay` package available on CRAN in order to export/import GGplot graph to R. You'll be needing both `DescribeDisplay` and `ggplot2` or the "built-in" `graphics` package, i.e. you can use both `qplot` or `plot` to get the graph.

Once saved, the display description can be imported with: see [the link](http://www.ggobi.org/describe-display/) =)

About "click-and-get-info" feature - RApache is not going to help you either! There are `identify` and `locator` functions that work with the `graphics`, and can help you with click-and-get-info within R (see *Maindonald, J.H. - "Using R for Data Analysis and Graphics" - 3.4. Identification and Location on the Figure Region*, it's free and available [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/usingR.pdf)), but if you're planing to do something more ambitious on the web, refer to HTML `<map>` and `<area>` tags, here's [an example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap). Then I guess you'll be doing some JavaScript magic (defining coordinates and stuff), which is, if I may notice, quite ambitious.

See also: `graphics::text` and `ggplot2::geom_text`.